# Color coding summary tasks in using VBA in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

we use a stage-gate framework and would like to color code each of the stages based on our colors. I've got the following code working, however, it continues to loop through about 30 times.

It doesn't need to keep looping though but not sure how to handle it. Any help to make this better would be appreciated.

Each Stage is at the first Summary level

```
Sub FindFieldByPriority2()
Dim ProjTasks   As Tasks
Dim ProjTask    As Task

Set ProjTasks = ActiveProject.Tasks
        If ProjTask.Summary = True Then
            
            Find Field:="Name", Test:="contains", Value:="STAGE 1 -"
            SelectRow
            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=50417
            
            Find Field:="Name", Test:="contains", Value:="STAGE 2 -"
            SelectRow
            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=1597656
            
            Find Field:="Name", Test:="contains", Value:="STAGE 3 -"
            SelectRow
            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=4925715
            
            Find Field:="Name", Test:="contains", Value:="STAGE 4 -"
            SelectRow
            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=4898666
    End If

Next ProjTask
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code loops through the tasks and formats level 1 summary tasks based on the task name.

```
Sub FormatLevel1SummaryTasks()

    FilterApply "All Tasks"
    SelectAll
    OutlineShowAllTasks
    
    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not tsk Is Nothing Then
            If tsk.OutlineLevel = 1 Then
                
                Find Field:="Unique ID", Test:="equals", Value:=tsk.UniqueID
                If ActiveCell.Task.UniqueID = tsk.UniqueID Then
        
                    Select Case Left$(tsk.Name, 10)
                        Case Is = "STAGE 1 - "
                            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=50417
                        Case Is = "STAGE 2 - "
                            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=1597656
                        Case Is = "STAGE 3 - "
                            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=4925715
                        Case Is = "STAGE 4 - "
                            Font32Ex Color:=16777215, CellColor:=4898666
                        Case Else
                    End Select
    
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next tsk
    
End Sub
```

Note: to only format visible tasks, remove the first three lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to successively apply a filter to isolate each of the phases. Do a SelectAll for the filtered set and apply color formatting en masse.
John